# How to use innerJoinAndSelect to merge two tables into one?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

everybody! I have two related tables, and one of them contains column with id of the second table's record. So I want to extract several properties from the second table and сoncatenate them with the result of the first one.

I faced the problem which is when I try to make a query via SQL string(that is `` SELECT * FROM `characters` `c` INNER JOIN `money` `m` ON `c`.`bank` = `m`.`id` WHERE uuid = ? ``) — everything works fine. But when I do the same things via TypeORM the *queryBuilder* returns only data from the first table (`characters`).

My **chatacters** Entity:

```
export default class Character extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  uuid: number;

  ...

  @OneToOne(() => Money)
  @JoinColumn()
  bank: Money;

  ...

  public static async findByUuid(uuid: number): Promise<Character> {
    return await getManager()
      .createQueryBuilder(Character, "c")
      .innerJoinAndSelect(Money, "m", "c.bank = m.id")
      .where("uuid = :uuid ", { uuid })
      .getOne();
  }
}
```

My **money** Entity:

```
export default class Money extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   public id: number;

  @Column()
  type: number;

  @Column()
  holder: string;

  @Column()
  balance: number;
}
```

I tried to replace `c.bank = m.id` with `c.bankId = m.id`, but it also didn't work. I tried to remove @OneToOne relation, but I got the same effect. I turned "logging" option on and copied SQL string generated, then I executed it via PhpMyAdmin and ... It worked! It seems TypeORM modifies query's result and gives me the row of the first table only. I don't understand what goes wrong. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in two ways:

#### 1. Using `QueryBuilder` (like you tried):

```js
const character = await getManager()
      .createQueryBuilder(Character, "c")
      .innerJoinAndSelect("c.bank", "bank")
      .where("c.uuid = :uuid ", { uuid })
      .getOne();
return character;
```

#### 2. Using `findOne`:

```js
const character = await getManager()
      .getRepository(Character)
      .findOne({ relations: ["bank"], where: { uuid } });
return character;
```

Now you should be able to access `bank` using `character.bank`

### Update: For removing the foreign key `bankId` from `characters` table, you can do something like below.

```js
@OneToOne(() => Money, { createForeignKeyConstraints: false })
bank: Money;
```

See [the reference from typeorm documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations-faq.md#avoid-foreign-key-constraint-creation).

As you said, if some other server is trying to save id into `bank` field, that would be problematic because your `Character` entity's `bank` property is of type `Money`. So better if you change the name of the relation to something else to avoid conflict.

Hope this helps. Cheers  !!!

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Is there way to extract only specific fiekda from the second table? What if I want to prevent generating additional column "bankId"? For example, I do not want to create another Entity which I'm not going to use. So that I do not point any relationship between these two tables, but I wish to union them(or, if tlit is possible, only fields I need).

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent generating `bankId` column in `characters` table, but want to join them anyway?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My database is used by another server that stores id into 'bank' field(but this one is removed and the 'bankId' column is generated instead). So I fear the potential conflict. Anyway, I would be glad to know about all ways to do this trick(without creating extra columns, entities, etc.)

Comment: `bankId` column is generated because we use `@JoinColumn()` annotation in `Character` entity. I'll update my answer with how to remove the foreign key reference from your entity. You might have to test it to make sure though.

Comment: Your solution works, but it is still created 'bankId' column... I have tried to insert a row with 'bank' field, but, unfortunately, I caught the error that this column doesn't exist. I'd like just to know, is there way to do the similar effect without relations?

Comment: It seems I found the solution... I can just point exactly how the column should be named: `@JoinColumn({ name: 'bank' })`. And everything works great.

Comment: I forgot to remove the annotation `@JoinColumn()`. Yes, but then that means you're going to have a foreign key in your table named `bank`. Maybe I didn't understand you properly earlier. Anyway, good luck!